# How to change the currently visible mouse cursor graphic programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, cursor, mouse

Is there a way to change the currently visible mouse cursor (regardless of which application has focus) to a different graphical icon?

I want to load a custom "invisible" PNG or ICO image as the mouse cursor when the user presses a shortcut key to hide the mouse cursor, then restore the original cursor when user moves the mouse.

My app will be listening for a hotkey combination, and when detected, the global cursor should be changed, regardless of whether my app has the focus, or another app is in the foreground.

The goal is to allow the user to hide the cursor while typing, and bring it back immediately upon moving the mouse.

I think the functionality should be as follows:

1. When hotkey combination is detected:

   a. Determine which cursor is
   currently visible (OCR_NORMAL, OCR_IBEAM, etc...)

   b. For that
   system cursor, replace the system cursor graphic with an invisible
   graphic (one made of entirely transparent pixels)
2. When a move of the mouse is detected

   a. Determine current visible cursor (OCR_NORMAL, OCR_IBEAM, etc...)

   b. For that system cursor, replace the blank graphic with the original system cursor
   graphic.

Can anyone help me 1) determine which system cursor is currently visible, and 2) change this cursor to another cursor graphic, regardless of which application is currently in focus?  I don't care what programming language is used, but C++ may be best since it is used commonly to interact with the Windows API.

Comment: You don't have to replace it to hide it, all cursors functions are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors

Comment: "The goal is to allow the user to hide the cursor while typing, and bring it back immediately upon moving the mouse."  Windows already does that, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanPotter the problem is that most apps do not support the "hide cursor when typing" feature.  This is only supported by a select few which use Windows common controls, such as Notepad and Wordpad.

Comment: @SimonMourier The main issue I have encountered is that I can't find a way to hide the cursor globally: it only disappears when hovering over the app that calls ShowCursor().  Since I want the cursor to disappear globally, I was trying a different approach: changing the cursor's graphic. I was hoping this could be done globally instead of being restricted to the calling app.

Comment: This is a by-design Windows behavior so one app can't really mess with others. Only the end-user can deliberately choose to change the cursor globally.

Comment: @SimonMourier I totally get the protection aspect, but it seems like there would be some sort of access to that API...  I mean it is Windows, after all :)

Comment: I agree with Simon. It is by design. And there is no api to achieve what you want. 
"allow the user to hide the cursor while typing" I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://superuser.com/questions/54147/programming-productivity-how-to-hide-cursor-while-typing

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT  "It's not possible.  So here is a link that does it."  HAHAHA Thank you for providing this link. It is exactly what I was seeking.  So he is basically 1) cloning the existing system mouse cursors, 2) creating blank cursors, 3) when a keypress is detected, copying the blank cursors onto the system cursors, and 4) when the mouse is moved, copying the cloned original cursors back to the system cursors.